# ZF2 Image path after upload and display

Tags: zend-framework2

I have virtual host config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mytest.local
    DocumentRoot G:/PHP/mytest/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory G:/PHP/mytest/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the UploadForm.php

```
$file->getFilterChain()->attachByName(
    'filerenameupload',
    array(
        'target'          => './public/uploads/',
        'overwrite'       => true,
        'use_upload_name' => true,
        'randomize' => true,
    )
);
```

I get the image url after upload completed from my database like this:

```
./public/uploads/4f3c8338_54f0f253_070305-076_5321f51f96ff1_532866a55f4b6.jpg
```

How can I display this image link in my view when my vhost config default to public folder?
Try with:

```
'./public/uploads/4f3c8338_54f0f253_070305-076_5321f51f96ff1_532866a55f4b6.jpg'
```

also

```
$this->basepath() . './public/uploads/4f3c8338_54f0f253_070305-076_5321f51f96ff1_532866a55f4b6.jpg';
```

but non above working.
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by 'display this image link' you mean show the image in HTML, it would be:

```
<img src="/uploads/4f3c8338_54f0f253_070305-076_5321f51f96ff1_532866a55f4b6.jpg">
```